# Mongo DB driver "Cannot find module 'bson'." and no intellisense

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript

I'm setting up a server, and want to use Mongo DB as my Data storage but I am not getting any intellisence from Visual Studio Code whatsoever and adding and removing flow. When I "CTRL + Click" MongoClient I get 2 same errors i.e. Cannot find module 'bson'. when I hover over bson
   it shows the location to AppData/Local/Microsoft/TypeScript/3.4/node_modules/@types/bson/index
could not find module bson  on line :

```
   `import { ObjectID, Timestamp } from 'bson';`
```

and line" 
   `export { Binary, DBRef, Decimal128, Double, Long, MaxKey, MinKey, ObjectID, ObjectId, Timestamp } from 'bson';`

What I've tried is installing mode and various npm packages you'll see from my `package.json` file and running `npm install`, `npm update` and installing node - gyp for global but still the error has persisted

```
package.json

{
  "name": "MadLibs_SERVER",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/bson": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/mongodb": "^3.1.22",
    "@types/node": "^11.13.0",
    "bson": "^4.0.2",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "mongodb": "^3.2.3",
    "node": "^11.13.0"
  }
}
```

**Update 1 :**
  After re installing all modules i.e express and mongodb and removing all others now I still don't get intellisense but opening the file I am getting more errors `Cannot find type definition file for 'node'.`
now my package has only mongodb and express but still no fix.

Comment: Did you `npm install --save bson` already too?

Comment: Probably missing a `typeRoots` from your [`tsconfig`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types). Also the whole `AppData` thing looks quite horribly like a "global install". You should only be installing "locally" to the project as noted above. Also FYI the `mongodb` package actually has `bson` as an installed dependency, and even **re-exports** the very same `ObjectId` and `Timestamp` declarations from that module. Just please don't attempt to use it from a browser.

Comment: @Rafael, I have tried this but no luck :(. Neil I am new to nodejs and don't quite get the good habits of it yet but the error is preventing me to go further, a fix commented can be helpful here :D. I think the global installs were only because of the fixes on the internet and the bson for the Flow module(which I removed).

Comment: I think the problem is that it's finding `bson` globally instead of locally on the `node_modules` folder is there a way I can force it. I have unistalled/removed bson and @types/bson globally but still no effect.